# Setting Language of API in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am trying to implement the [DuckDuckGo Instant Answer Api](https://duckduckgo.com/api) into my NodeJS application.
For that I request data from the Api using Node Request.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=Hamburg&format=json&pretty=1', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(body));
  }
})
```

This gives me the result in English, but I would like to have it in German. In my browser it is in German. How can I change my code so I can get the data in German in NodeJS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `kad` key with a proper locale.

As so:

http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=Hamburg&format=json&pretty=1&kad=de_DE